# Error when mounting an EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mount

I am following an online tutorial to set up an EC2 instance for a group project. http://www.developintelligence.com/blog/2017/02/analyzing-4-million-yelp-reviews-python-aws-ec2-instance/.

The instance I used is r3.4xlarge, the tutorial says if I chose an instance with an SSD, I need to mount that and run the following code:

```
lsblk
sudo mkdir /mnt/ssd
sudo mount /dev/xvdb /mnt/ssd
sudo chown -R ubuntu /mnt/ssd
```

`lsblk` shows the following:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0  300G  0 disk
```

However, when I run `sudo mount /dev/xvdb /mnt/ssd`, it gives me the error:

```
   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdb,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Could someone provide a solution to this error? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to create a filesystem on it first: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb` (or choose other fs if `ext4` does not suit your needs)

Comment: @zerkms It says `mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015) Could not open /dev/xvdb: Permission denied` should I add sudo at the beginning?

Comment: Yep............

Comment: @zerkms it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before one mounts a filesystem in linux - the filesystem should be created.

In this case it might be

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
```

This would create an ext4 filesystem on a `/dev/xvdb` device.